# In recast, why is a Literal that is a string not a StringLiteral?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

This mainly stems from me not finding extended documentation to read, apart from the bits that are on the related github pages.

```
const recast = import("recast");
const example = "let s = 'some text';";
let ast = recast.parse(example);
recast.types.namedTypes.StringLiteral.check(ast.program.body[0].declarations[0].init) === false;
recast.types.namedTypes.Literal.check(ast.program.body[0].declarations[0].init) === true;
typeof ast.program.body[0].declarations[0].init.value === "string";
```

I was expecting the `StringLiteral` check to result in `true`, why is it not? My best guess is, that `StringLiteral` is something, that doesn't occur in vanilla javascript, but e.g. in typescript or related.

As i don't have proper documentation, i am going by best-guess, which is sadly often not a good idea. I'd be thankful for links to anything informative.

Side question: Is there a good way to check, whether a string literal is a valid identifier name, or do i have to do that with regex?